# How can I change the starting point and end point location of a html5 canvas line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can draw line with the following code successfully:

```
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(200,100);
    ctx.stroke();
```

Is it possible to change the start point or end point location(i.e. coordinate) of the line?
Do I need to clear the whole context?
I want to the mouse to drag either end for drawing a circle or sector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) to move your canvas to (x, y)

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.translate(50, 50); // move to (50, 50)
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(200,100);
    ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: But that won't move or stretch an existing line that was drawn previously, which is what the OP seems to want to do.

Comment: Yes, I want to move the line.

Comment: Hmm. IMHO, it's impossible to move existing line.  You only can repaint your canvas